# The set of discontinuous points is countable union of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Im reading chapter9 Category, Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed, talking about discontinuous functions of metric space. Here is a proof for a theorem that the set of discontinuous points is the countable union of closed sets in R:
[image]
[image]

Definition of D(f) is:

[image]

Definition of $ω_f(a)$ is:
[image]

Definition of ω(f; I) is:
[image]

Actually, I have some questions,:

1. Let $F_n= \{a : ω_f(a) \geq 1/n \}$, then $F_1$ belongs to $F_2$, $F_2$ belongs to $F_3$, $F_3$ belongs to $F_4$ and so forth, is that right?
2. What's the reason for "why"? I mean if question1 is yes, then union of $F_n$ seems to be no sense cos union of $F_n$ will = $lim F_n$ when $n$ goes to infinity.
3. In $\{a : ω_f(a) \geq \xi \text{ for some } \xi > 0\}$, $\xi$ should as small as possible(basically, $\xi>0$), is that right?
4. Is {a:$ω_f(a) < r$} a subset of or equivalent to ${I: ω(f:I) < r}$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes: if $\omega_f(a)\ge\frac1n$, then certainly $\omega_f(a)\ge\frac1{n+1}$, so $F_n\subseteq F_{n+1}$ for each $n$.
2. The statement that $D(f)=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n$ really does require proof, though the proof is very easy. First off, it’s clear that if $\omega_f(a)\ge\frac1n$ then $\omega_f(a)>0$, so $F_n\subseteq D(f)$ for each $n\ge 1$. Thus, $D(f)\supseteq\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n$. Now suppose that $a\in D(f)$. Then $\omega_f(a)>0$, so there is some positive integer $k$ such that $\frac1k<\omega_f(a)$. But then $a\in F_k\subseteq\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n$, and since $a$ was any element of $D(f)$, this implies that $D(f)\subseteq\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n$. Combining the inclusions, we see that $D(f)=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n$, as claimed.
3. Do you mean in the equality $\{a:\omega_f(a)>0\}=\{a:\omega_f(a)\ge\epsilon\text{ for some }\epsilon>0\}$? That step could just as well be omitted: in (2) above I showed directly that $D(f)=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}F_n$ without using $\{a:\omega_f(a)\ge\epsilon\text{ for some }\epsilon>0\}$ at all. I don’t think that it contributes anything to one’s understanding of the argument.
4. $\{a:\omega_f(a)<r\}$ is a set of real numbers, a subset of $\Bbb R$; $\{I:\omega(f;I)<r\}$ is a set of bounded intervals in $\Bbb R$. These two sets don’t even have the same kind of elements: the elements of the first set are individual real numbers, while the elements of the second set are bounded intervals of real numbers. Thus, the two sets are very different: not only is it impossible for them to be equal to each other, it’s impossible for either of them to be a subset of the other.

Comment: I see it. Thank u!

Comment: @Frank: You’re welcome!

Comment: for problem3, Im just a little confusing about "some ε>0" cos english is not my native language. Does "some ε>0" mean a fixed number larger than 0? If so, for example {a:$ω_f$(a) >= ε while ε=1}, then {a:$ω_f$(a) >= ε while ε=1} = {a:$ω_f$(a) >=1} which belongs to a subset of D(f) instead of equivalence between them.

Comment: @Frank: ‘$\omega_f(a)\ge\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$’ means $\exists\epsilon>0\big(\omega_f(a)\ge\epsilon\big)$; does that help? (And of course it’s clearly true, because we can take $\epsilon=\omega_f(a)$.)

Comment: I mean ϵ represents a extremely small value that is larger than 0, is that right?

Comment: Im so sorry to talk about such a boring question of ϵ. However, I think it could be important for me to understand some notations deeply. I really appreciate ur kindness and patience.^_^

Comment: @Frank: $\epsilon$ could be any positive real number at all; it’s just that we’re more interested in what happens when it’s small. We can talk meaningfully about $\{a:\omega_f(a)\ge 100\}$, for instance.

Comment: Awesome, make sense a lot^_^

Comment: Yes. But i think the range of {a:$ω_f$(a)≥100} may be a little small than D(f) that should be {a:$ω_f$(a) > 0} cos D(f) will collect all the discontinuous points in a function while {a:$ω_f$(a)≥100} just collect some of them actually.

Comment: @Frank: In general **every** set of the form $\{a:\omega_f(a)\ge\epsilon\}$ collects only some of them; that’s why we need their union to get all of $D(f)$. The smaller you take $\epsilon$, the more of the points you get.

Comment: Yes, I agree with u. But the problem is "{a:$ω_f$(a) >= ε for some ε > 0}" showed above does not include a symbol of union there, which puzzles me a lot.

Comment: @Frank: It’s implicit: $$\{a:\omega_f(a)\ge\epsilon\text{ for some }\epsilon>0\}$$ means $$\{a:\exists\epsilon>0(\omega_f(a)\ge\epsilon)\}\;,$$ which is equal to $$\bigcup_{\epsilon>0}\{a:\omega_f(a)\ge\epsilon\}\;.$$

Comment: OhhhhhK, get it^_^!