# Why does the set of rational numbers be a countable union of closed sets?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Im reading Chapter9 Category, Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed, talking about discontinuous functions of metric space,:
[image]

At the bottom, the author claimed that Q is $F_σ$ set, which means that the set of rational numbers is a countable union of closed sets, Why?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is the union of the singleton sets $\{q\}$ for $q\in\Bbb Q$; each of these is closed, and there are only countably many of them, since $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Awesome, Make sense a lot! Thank u^_^

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: Brian is a genius !

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: BTW, I've posted another question before this. [Link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588510/the-set-of-discontinuous-points-is-countable-union-of-closed-sets). Can u help me solve it? Thank u in advance^_^

Comment: I’ll take a look in a little bit.

Comment: @DonAnselmo: Correct, he is a genius^_^ He can do everything, at least in Math.

Comment: and by the way @BrianM.Scott is the topology guru here in MSE. He is a walking topology encyclopedia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, then there is bijection from $\mathbb{Q} \to N$. 
So, can think of $\mathbb{Q}$ as $\{ x_0, x_1, x_2 , x_3, ........ \} $

But,

$$ \{x_0,x_1,.... \} = \bigcup \{x_n\} $$

Now, we all know singletons are closed sets. (PRoof?).

Answer (score 7):

$$\mathbb{Q} = \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}} \left\{q\right\}$$