# Mistake in a proof

Tags: real-analysis

Consider [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588510/the-set-of-discontinuous-points-is-countable-union-of-closed-sets). The author quotes a proof that says that there exists a neighbourhood of $x$ such that $\omega (f;I)) <r$. I do not agree with that. Consider
\begin{align*}
f(x) =
\begin{cases} x &\text{ if }x<0 \\
x+1 &\text{ if }x \geq 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then for this what is written is not true.

What is going on here? If my counter example is false, can someone explain to me why the result (in general) should be true?

Comment: What exactly is the claim that you disagree with? What are the hypotheses on $f$, $x$, and $r$? And where exactly did you find this claim? In your link, I see the claim that *if* $\omega_f(x)<r$, then there exists $I$ such that $\omega(f;I)<r$...

Comment: If the infimum of  a set of real numbers is less than $r$, then some element of the set is less than  $r$.

Comment: Hi. Apologies if I havent made it clear but I do not agree that such I exists. In particular, in my example,  I do not think such neighborhood of 0 exists. Also to address the other comment, I am afraid I cant see how an infimum plays a role here as we are dealing with supremums.

Comment: Read the definition of $\omega_f(a)$. It is an infumum.

Comment: Hi. Please read the comment to the answer. I think this is where the essence of my question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no error in that proof.

For your example, $\omega_f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } x=0 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$

If $a = 0$ and $\omega_f(a) < r$ then $r > 1$.

Then $a \in I = \left(\frac{1-r}3, \frac{r-1}3\right)$ satisfies
$$\omega(f;I) = \left(\frac{r-1}3+1\right) - \frac{1-r}3 = \frac{2r+1}{3}$$
where
$$1 = \frac{2+1}{3} \leq \frac{2r+1}3 < \frac{2r+r}{3} = r$$

This agrees with the statement in the questioned proof.

---

More generally, what we have is this: If $r$ satisfies
$$\omega_f(a) := \inf_{I \ni a \\ I \text{ open}} \omega(f;I) < r$$
then since $r$ is not a lower bound of $\{\omega(f;I) : I\in a, I\text{ open}\}$, there is some open $I_0 \ni a$ such that $\omega(f;I_0) < r$.

Or in the contrapositive, if no such $I_0$ existed such that $\omega(f;I_0) < r$, then $r$ would be a lower bound on that set, showing $\omega_f(a) \geq r$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. I think I understand that example. But I am struggling with something else. Isn’t the equivalent definition of w as given wrong? In particular surely the infimum need not equal to the limit as h tends to 0.

Comment: @MathsWizzard First, the _definition_ of $\omega_f$ given is the infimum I gave in the answer.  Since $I \subseteq J \implies \omega(f;I) \leq \omega(f;J)$ and the balls centered at $a$ form a neighborhood base, it is also given by that limit as $h\to 0^+$.

Comment: @MathsWizzard I am still left quite puzzled by why you think there _must_ be an error somewhere there.

Comment: Hi. I think I understand now. The issue for me was the multiplies equalities in the definition of $\omega$. For some reason I thought that this equality need not hold but due to your comment above I am now convinced. I was looking at the linked question to use that result to prove something else. In particular, that the discontinuities are of Baire Category one. However, in the question given to me we assumed that $f$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of functions. Comparing with this, I see that this assumption is not needed so I thought perhaps there is an issue with the proof. Combining

Comment: these two things, I somehow convinced my self that the definition of $\omega$ is wrong. Apologies for the perhaps badly written question. Should I keep it or delete it considering the amount of negative response and close votes?